# What's the best way to extend the functionality of factory-produced classes outside of the module in python?

Tags: python, factory, icalendar

I've been reading lots of previous SO discussions of factory functions, etc. and still don't know what the best (pythonic) approach is to this particular situation. I'll admit up front that i am imposing a somewhat artificial constraint on the problem in that i want my solution to work without modifying the module i am trying to extend: i could make modifications to it, but let's assume that it must remain as-is because i'm trying to understand best practice in this situation.

I'm working with the http://pypi.python.org/pypi/icalendar module, which handles parsing from and serializing to the Icalendar spec (hereafter ical). It parses the text into a hierarchy of dictionary-like "component" objects, where every "component" is an instance of a trivial derived class implementing the different valid ical types (VCALENDAR, VEVENT, etc.) and they are all spit out by a recursive factory from the common parent class:

```
class Component(...):
  @classmethod
  def from_ical(cls, ...)
```

I have created a 'CalendarFile' class that extends the ical 'Calendar' class, including in it generator function of its own:

```
class CalendarFile(Calendar):
  @classmethod
  def from_file(cls, ics):
```

which opens a file (`ics`) and passes it on:

```
     instance = cls.from_ical(f.read())
```

It initializes and modifies some other things in `instance` and then returns it. The problem is that `instance` ends up being a `Calendar` object instead of a `CalendarFile` object, in spite of `cls` being `CalendarFile`. Short of going into the factory function of the ical module and fiddling around in there, is there any way to essentially "recast" that object as a 'CalendarFile'?

The alternatives (again without modifying the original module) that I have considered are:

- make the `CalendarFile` class a has-a `Calendar` class (each instance creates its own internal instance of a `Calendar` object), but that seems methodically stilted.

  fiddle with the returned object to give it the methods it needs (i know there's a term for creating a customized object but it escapes me).

  make the additional methods into functions and just have them work with instances of `Calendar`.

  or perhaps the answer is that i shouldn't be trying to subclass from a module in the first place, and this type of code belongs in the module itself.

Again i'm trying to understand what the "best" approach is and also learn if i'm missing any alternatives. Thanks.

Comment: There's not enough code in your question to tell what you're doing. From what you have written it sounds like `CalendarFile.from_file()` calls itself recursively which doesn't make sense. Also it is incorrect to call them generator functions, which has a unique meaning unrelated to all this in Python. You also need to define in what sense you mean "best".

Comment: @martineau - I think the problem is that Calendar.from_file() creates Calendar objects even when called from a subclass. This could be considered a bug in Calendar because it has a class method that doesn't honor the cls arg passed in.

Comment: @Flandry - I think all of your options are reasonable. I kinda like has-a-Calendar the best because at least its all encapsulated in a single place.

Comment: @martineau I'm extending the functionality of the Calendar class with diff, merge, etc, but first need to be able to instantiate the CalendarFile class. The way that the Calendar class is created from data is by calling the from_ical() classmethod (described above), which returns an object typed according to what is parsed from the ical string passed (hence a calendar if a complete ical is passed to it). I was hoping that if i called that classmethod from a derived CalendarFile classmethod, it would return an instance of the derived class (wishful thinking perhaps) instead of the parent class.

Comment: (too long for one comment) As it doesn't, I need to know the best way to extend the functionality of that class without either adding new methods to the Calendar class itself (in the module) or modifying the factory (also in the module). Is that clearer?

Comment: @tdelaney - yes, i thought it was a bug but i'm not that familiar with the factory design paradigm. Maybe it's just a ghost of my CS classes, but i feel kind of dirty about making it a has-a class. Just wanted some wiser heads to comment, so thank you.

Comment: @Flandry: Yes, that's clearer. Seems like you could add a constructor method to the `CalendarFile` class that accepts a `Calendar` instance as an argument and then call it with the instance created by `cls.from_ical()` in your `CalendarFile.from_file()` method.

Comment: Wouldn't that amount to giving `CalendarFile` a has_a relationship to `Calendar` as i described? I'd either store a reference to the `Calendar` object as a class variable or have to copy all the internal data from the `Calendar` object to the new `CalendarFile` instance being constructed, wouldn't i? I'm not all that expert in python so maybe i'm missing a third alternative.

Comment: It appears that taking the `Calendar` object resulting from my call to `from_file()` in the OP and simply doing `object.__class__ = CalendarFile` gives a functional `CalendarFile` object, and since i do all the initiation of class variables in the `.from_file()` call, my code now works. Considering that the consensus so far is that it's a bug for the factory to not return the subclassed type of object, this seems like the best solution and means that if/when the bug is fixed, no changes are necessary. Are there any unexpected side effects to this?

Comment: I'm also still interested in opinions on the "big picture", not just specific technical solutions.

Comment: If these Classes can't be instantiated at all by calling `Calendar`, then this isn't a "bug" that will be fixed, but a fundamental design flaw (IMO). I don't like editing `object.__class__` but that doesn't sound any more outlandish than what the designers of the package have already done! It seems very strange to me to use OO design but then cripple it like this.

Comment: @Flandry I've looked at the ical code and while I still think it uses OO constructs in an awkward way, I now strongly feel you should change your approach. You should take the first option; `CalendarFile` should have a `Calendar` object in it. Subclassing from `Calendar` is totally contrary to the idiom of the ical code; it's just not designed to be subclassed that way.

Comment: Okay that's a good point. Instead of extending the Calendar class what i am really doing is making a `CalendarTools` class, which can have a `Calendar`. That better fits what i'm doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, I would expect an alternative constructor defined as a classmethod to simply call the class's standard constructor, transforming the arguments that it receives into valid arguments to the standard constructor.

```
>>> class Toy(object):
...     def __init__(self, x):
...         self.x = abs(x)
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return 'Toy({})'.format(self.x)
...     @classmethod
...     def from_string(cls, s):
...         return cls(int(s))
... 
>>> Toy.from_string('5')
Toy(5)
```

In most cases, I would strongly recommend something like this approach; this is the gold standard for alternative constructors.

But this is a special case.

I've now looked over the source, and I think the *best* way to add a new class is to edit the module directly; otherwise, scrap inheritance and take option one (your "has-a" option). The different classes are all slightly differentiated versions of the same container class -- they shouldn't really even be separate classes. But if you want to add a new class in the idiom of the code as it it is written, you have to add a new class to the module itself. Furthermore, `from_iter` is deceptively named; it's not really a constructor at all. I think it should be a standalone function. It builds a whole tree of components linked together, and the code that builds the individual components is buried in a chain of calls to various factory functions that also should be standalone functions but aren't. IMO much of that code *ought* to live in `__init__` where it would be useful to you for subclassing, but it doesn't.

Indeed, none of the subclasses of `Component` even add any methods. By adding methods to your subclass of `Calendar`, you're completely disregarding the actual idiom of the code. I don't like its idiom very much but by disregarding that idiom, you're making it even worse. If you don't want to modify the original module, then forget about inheritance here and give your object a has-a relationship to `Calendar` objects. Don't modify `__class__`; establish your *own* OO structure that follows standard OO practices.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how that would work. The problem is that the API of ical specifies `Calendar` objects can only be obtained through the `.from_ical()` classmethod, so no amount of fiddling with constructors is going to help as far as i can tell.

Comment: Ok, I wondered if that was the case. But it's possible that the second approach will still work; after all, every (new-style) object has a `__new__` and an `__init__` method. But the `__init__` method may not do anything; it all depends. How much state does a `Calendar` object actually contain? You might be able to write your own function that does the initialization.